# Custom zener diode in LTSPICE

Tags: diodes, ltspice, zener

I want to use the diode 1N4571 (Vbrkdn=6.4V) and 1N4761 (Vbrkdn= 75V) in my circuit. Please help me design these zener diodes in LTSPICE.

Answer (score 9):

A quick way of adjusting the zener voltage of a spice model, is by creating an alias to it and modifying the properties you need, e.g.:

The zener diode D1 uses a model called MYD, which is nothing but a copy of the built-in zener diode BZX84B8V2L but with a different zener voltage (5V in this case).

[image: Circuit]

You can also create a model from scratch using the directive "D":

[image: Circuit 2]

Comment: How to build a model from scratch or modify a model, can you please explain it in detail?

Comment: Just add a model directive on your circuit by clicking on .Spice Directive, and then writing the properties of your diode accordingly e.g. .model <model name> D (<property 1> <property 2>). For example if you want to create an almost ideal rectifier diode, create a model as follows: .model MYRECTIFIER D (Vfwd=1m)

Comment: http://ltwiki.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_LTspice#AKO_Aliases_.28A_Kind_Of.29